# How can I get the seed from the result of a LCG generator in Lua?

Tags: random, lua, lcg

I'm currently working on a Lua port of the [Library Of Babel](https://libraryofbabel.info/).

To my knowledge, it works by randomly generating the title and book by using the Hex, Bookshelf, Shelf, and Volume numbers. To implement this in Lua, I was using [randomlua](https://github.com/linux-man/randomlua), because Lua's built-in random API wasn't working well for me.

My only problem with it so far is that it doesn't allow me to reverse a result from the LCG to get the seed, which I need to do to implement searching for books. I'm not that intelligent when it comes to math like this, so I have no idea where to start.

This is the code for generating random numbers:

```lua
linear_congruential_generator = {}
linear_congruential_generator.__index = linear_congruential_generator

function linear_congruential_generator:random(a, b)
    local y = (self.a * self.x + self.c) % self.m
    self.x = y
    if not a then return y / 0x100000000
    elseif not b then
        if a == 0 then return y
        else return 1 + (y % a) end
    else
        return a + (y % (b - a + 1))
    end
end
```

I have absolutely no idea how I could reverse the function to make it return a seed where that result occurs.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

This is how I calculate the Title and Contents of a page:

```
local charset = {}  do -- [0-9a-zA-Z]
    for c = 48, 57  do table.insert(charset, string.char(c)) end
    for c = 65, 90  do table.insert(charset, string.char(c)) end
    for c = 97, 122 do table.insert(charset, string.char(c)) end
    table.insert(charset," ")
end
function randomString(length)
    if not length or length <= 0 then return '' end
    return randomString(length - 1) .. charset[generator:random(1, #charset)]
end
```

It's 8 characters for the Title, and 3200 Characters for the contents.

Comment: To calculate the initial seed after N invocations of random(), you have to move backwards N times.  What parameters do you use in LCG: ansi/nr/mvc ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff
I just added it to the original post, that's the only time I randomly generate a number in the code. The charset has 63 characters, so the parameters are `:random(1,63)`

Comment: Where do you initialize `self.a`, `self.c` and `self.m`?

Comment: You can see the full script in the [randomlua](https://github.com/linux-man/randomlua/blob/master/randomlua.lua)  github, I didn't modify it whatsoever.
```lua
function lcg(s, r)
 local temp = {}
 setmetatable(temp, linear_congruential_generator)
 temp.a, temp.c, temp.m = 1103515245, 12345, 0x100000000  --from Ansi C
 if r then
  if r == 'nr' then temp.a, temp.c, temp.m = 1664525, 1013904223, 0x100000000 --from Numerical Recipes.
  elseif r == 'mvc' then temp.a, temp.c, temp.m = 214013, 2531011, 0x100000000 end--from MVC
 end
 temp:randomseed(s)
 return temp
end
```
@EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Yes, there are three variants of the LCG there.  Which one do you use?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I am using the Linear Congruential Generator, not the Multiply With Carry or the Mersenne twister.

Comment: What are the arguments you pass for `lcg()` when you initialize the generator?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I am using lcg(0) to initialize.

Comment: This means your seed is `0` :-)  What is your Lua version?

Comment: Thats not the problem, the seed isn't always 0. I set the seed manually based on the Room, Wall, Shelf, and Volume.
So when I generate books, their seeds will be different to generate a different string.

What I'm trying to do is take a result, give it to the function, and I'll get a seed where that result will occur, basically the searching in the Library Of Babel.
I'm using Lua 5.1.
@EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: In Lua 5.1 your LCG is not reversible because you have changed constant `0x10000` to `0x100000000`.  Lua 5.1 can't exactly multiply two 32-bit numbers.

Comment: That must have been a typo, would it still be impossible to reverse if I fixed that or no?

Comment: Yes.  To make one step back: `x=(12345-x)*5275%0x10000`